# Understanding Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I am confused about the function of Apache ActiveMQ.

I downloaded ActiveMQ from [this link](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=%2Factivemq%2Fapache-activemq%2F5.6.0%2Fapache-activemq-5.6.0-bin.zip). 
So I use it this way (environment: Windows 7): I start the `bin/activemq.bat`, then it works.

My question is: Does this mean I start a server on my machine? When I initialize the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`, the broker URL is `tcp://localhost:61616`. But what if I want my machine to serve as a server and another machine to connect to my server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use the primary box as a server and have consumers/subscribers running on other boxes (which will need to connect to the server - you will need to specify the server hostname & port for the connection to be established) - once in place, the messages on the server (topic or queue) can be consumed by the clients.

If you one have one producer and one consumer, you can look into using queues - if you have more than one consumer/subscriber, you can look into setting up a topic to which the consumers will subscribe to.  Messages need to be inserted to the topic/queue as needed.

You can specify the server information in your code or preferably in the config file.

For reference to topologies:
http://activemq.apache.org/topologies.html

Also, you can choose to persist your messages or not based on your use case.  Kaha DB is the preferred route (specially if performance is of concern).

Useful examples:

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/12/jms-patterns-with-activemq.html

http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/05/java-client-to-sendreceive-messages-for.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I have already implemented the publisher/subscriber on one machine using "localhost". But I am now having difficulty in using two different machines. For the server(or broker) side, I should start the server(activemq.bat), but on the client side, I don't need to start the activemq.bat, right? What should be the ip address in the configuration file(activemq.xml) on the server side? localhost or my actual ipaddress?

Comment: you can run the broker on the "server" - for consumers, you simply need to have the  activemq jar files (& log4j/slf4j jar files) in your project running on the client computer - you will need to specify the server/broker to connect to - use nslookup or ipconfig to confirm the host name where you are running the broker and specify that IP address (and the port on which the broker is listening on - 61616 or else) in order for the consumer (client) to connect to the broker (consumer).

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. But can I ask you another question? By default, the activemq uses tcp protocol. Now I am configuring it to use ssl. On one machine, it makes no difference. But after I deploy it on two machines, it becomes much slower. Have you had any experience using ssl? Is this normal?

Comment: hope you got your answer - ssl usage will slow things down but not too massively - depends on how you've configured things and there is nothing in the code that's causing the slowdown

Comment: Yeah. I made a mistake by creating a connection for each message sent, which wasted a lot of time on handshake. One connection for one publisher now works well.

Answer (score -3):

Apache ActiveMQ ™ is the most popular and powerful open source messaging and Integration Patterns server 
& it act like a third party server.

Apache ActiveMQ is fast, supports many Cross Language Clients and Protocols, comes with easy to use Enterprise Integration Patterns and many advanced features while fully supporting JMS 1.1 and J2EE 1.4. Apache ActiveMQ is released under the Apache 2.0 License.

ActiveMQ have the capabilities to send 100 MB single message framework and maintain 1000 concurrent connection simultaneously , for the further information you can check activemq.xml in your documentation.

[Further Info at here about the ActiveMQ](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/what-is-activemq.html)

Comment: What's this, some kind of advertisement?